# Which path for C++ in QNX7 should be included?

Tags: c++, include-path, qnx

There are existing two include paths（5.4.0， v1） and two libraries(libstdc++, libc++) for C++ project in QNX7.
When using v1 path, it looks like libc++ should be used only. 
I want to know the difference of them and features.

Answer (score 1):

Actually `QNX 7` supports both `libstdc++` (GNU) and `libc++` (LLVM). Both libraries implement `c++` standards and are used widely. You can choose which library to link against on compiling time.

For more info see: http://www.qnx.com/developers/docs/7.0.0/#com.qnx.doc.qnxsdp.migration/topic/cpp_apps.html
and http://www.qnx.com/developers/docs/7.0.0/#com.qnx.doc.neutrino.utilities/topic/q/qcc.html